# on deploying php project on another system shows an error as permission denied

Tags: php, image, permission-denied

when i have tried to deploy a php project in another system i got a error like this

```
Warning: imagejpeg() [function.imagejpeg]: Unable to open 'image.jpg' for writing: Permission denied in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/WISMAN/pmhome.php on line 61
```

here i am getting a json after calling a web service to get a json as a response which contains a image in the string form,which i am encoding it into an image and saving it as image.jpeg but shows this one

```
 <?php
 $userid=$_SESSION[user_id];
 //echo $userid;
 $useridofuser=array(
 'user_id'=> "$userid");
  //echo json_encode($useridofuser);//coverting the vlaues collected from form  into json
        //calling the web service
      $url='webservice url';
    $data=$useridofuser;
 //echo("Input to Server : ".$data."\n");
    $ch=curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($useridofuser));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/json"));
    $response=  curl_exec($ch);
   echo('\n'."Server response : \n \n".$response);
    curl_close($ch);
    //parsing the json response from server 
    $jsonde="$response";
    $json_o=json_decode($jsonde);
    $json_a=json_decode($jsonde,true);
    //echo("$json_a");
    $company_name=$json_a[user_data][company_name];
    $name=$json_a[user_data][name];
    $registration_date=$json_a[user_data][registration_date];
    $user_id=$json_a[user_data][user_id];
    $product_id=$json_a[product_data][0][product_id];
    $product_registration_id=$json_a[product_data][0][product_registration_id];
    $product_name=$json_a[product_data][0][product_name];
    $registration_date=$json_a[product_data][0][registration_date];
    $image=$json_a[product_data][0][image];
    $expiry_date=$json_a[product_data][0][expiry_date];
    $product_evaluation_level=$json_a[product_data][0][product_evaluation_level];
 $_SESSION[regid]=$product_registration_id;
if($product_evaluation_level=="1")
{
    $level=trial;
}
$image_base64="$image";
$img = imagecreatefromstring(base64_decode($image_base64));
if($img != false)
{
imagejpeg($img, 'image.jpg');
} ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You just don't have enough privileges for writing to destination folder. Your server is probably running under user `apache`, `httpd` or something like that and you have your user like `Sree`.

Therefore you have to be either in one group and have [`chmod`](http://www.linuxnix.com/2011/10/chmod-command-explained-linuxunix.html) set to `x7x` - writeable for group; or (not in the same group) `xx7` - writeable for all.

Not mentioning possible issues caused by [seLinux](http://www.lurking-grue.org/selinuxHOWTO.html) (which your system may be running).

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a write permission to your directory. Give it permission then it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Your application does not have write permissions in the target directory that you are trying to save the file into. you will need to log in using a secure shell and update the permissions using [chmod](http://www.computerhope.com/unix/uchmod.htm)